# Disable Firefox's right click context menu in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firefox, contextmenu, handsontable

I am trying to disable the context menu that pops up on right click for a specific `div`. In the render I do

```
<div onContextMenu={(e) => {
    console.log(e); 
    e.preventDefault(); 
    e.stopPropagation(); 
    return false
}}>
```

and it does print so I know its attached, but it still pops up in firefox ESR 60.8.0 even though its blocked in chrome.

Reason: I have a handsontable that I added a custom context menu to, and in firefox the native context menu renders on top of mine. Once I figure out how to block the context menu anywhere in firefox I will apply that to the handsontable in the custom renderer

EDIT: started bounty because none of the other hacks have worked for me and this is a pretty obscure case about a rare version of firefox

Comment: [This](https://jsfiddle.net/xpLny7g4/) works for me in a current Firefox version; does it work for you? Or is your question specific to a last year's Firefox version?

Comment: @Nickolay That works for me in the lastest firefox but I just discovered I have the [ESR](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/) version of firefox, and it is already on the latest version for ESR, version 60.8.0. So I guess I'm looking for a workaround for the older versions. For now I know that I can close it on escape butI don't want to make our users do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A coworker helped me figure this out. It was a problem with my firefox setup that came preconfigured on my work computer. To fix it I had to go to `about:config` url in firefox, and change the `dom.event.contextmenu.enabled` value by double clicking. This changed it from “modified boolean false” to “default boolean true”. Expected behavior with `e.preventDefault()` follows

Answer (score 6):

You need to cut the menu opening during the capture phase.

```
document.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(e) {
    if(e.target.id === "YOUR ELEMENT ID") { // identify your element here. You can use e.target.id, or e.target.className, e.target.classList etc...
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
}, true) // true means you are executing your function during capture phase
```

This code you can setup during componentDidMount or outside of your React code at all.

Comment: Very close! this disabled my custom context menu while the native one still pops up. Perhaps this is more related to handsontable than I thought...

Answer (score 3):

I just tested this in firefox, ESR 60.8 for Mac and it works, could you double check if it does also for you.

Please double check that the event that you are calling preventDefault is the correct one, I had many times the error in which e is undefined.

Also I assumed that you are using react from the tag and the syntax of the post

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="red" onContextMenu={(e) => {
    console.log(e);
    e.preventDefault(); 
    e.stopPropagation(); 
}}>hello click me</div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Example/>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
.red{
  background: red;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I am using react. Unfortunately that didn't work for me in firefox even though it worked in chrome. Every time, the event's type is "contextmenu" so i think thats the right event. The preventing default and stop propagation jus don't affect it

Comment: But did the code I just posted work for you? It's so weird, as it does work for me though... Might it be Mac, vs microsoft?

Comment: That's correct, it didn't work :( I have Firefox Quantum 60.8.0esr on windows 10 enterprise, not sure what to do but thanks for trying

Comment: @MarcSlothEastman: the ability to preventDefault the contextmenu event is supposed to be controlled by `dom.event.contextmenu.enabled`, which is `true` since 2000s.. maybe try in a clean Firefox profile?

Answer (score 1):

The last resort could be binding the listener on the `ref` of the element.

```
this.handsontableRef.addEventListener('contextmenu', (e)=> {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("open your context menu");
});
```

Tried this in Firefox, working for me. Share the exact code so that we can replicate on our end too.

Comment: says `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.hotTableComponent.current.addEventListener is not a function` https://jsfiddle.net/L892g65r/

Comment: Please read the answer properly. I said to add `listener` on  `reference` to your element, not add event listener on the React component. Anyways, you got the answer below.

Comment: Is this what you meant? https://jsfiddle.net/uo4eL9n8/1/ again, it works in chrome but not firefox for me (adding an event listener to the ref directly gave `this.hotTableComponent.addEventListener` is not a function)

Comment: You actually used the same reference for multiple DOM elements, updated the code, https://jsfiddle.net/eb3kwht4/. Please add the exact Firefox version, so that I can test it too.

Comment: Ahh ok, idk why it won't let me put the ref on the handsontable, only the div. My version is Firefox Quantum 60.8.0esr on windows 10 enterprise

Comment: I Think you need to go `let domNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.hotTableComponent)` to get the node which you can add the event listener to with `domNode.addEventListener(...)`

Comment: @MarcSlothEastman its working fine on Mac. https://prnt.sc/ouxwta. Could be windows related issue if its still not working,